# Event hub Send event to random partitions but exactly one partition

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have event hub publisher but it is duplicating messages across random partitions multiple times . I want parallel messages for huge number of messages coming in which should go into random but exactly in one partition from where the consumer should get the data .

How do I do that . This is causing the message to be duplicated .

```cs
EventHubProducerClientOptions producerClientOptions = new EventHubProducerClientOptions
{
    RetryOptions = new EventHubsRetryOptions
    {
        Mode = EventHubsRetryMode.Exponential,
        MaximumRetries = 30,
        TryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        MaximumDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
    }
};
using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

// Add events to the batch. An event is a represented by a collection of bytes and metadata.
eventBatch.TryAdd(eventMessage);

string logInfo = $"[PUBLISHED - [{EventId}]] =======> {message}";
logger.LogInformation(logInfo);

// Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
```

Comment: I'd advise reconsidering your call to `eventBatch.TryAdd`, as you're not respecting the return value.  If you're adding enough events that the batch is full, this could lead to data loss as events will silently be rejected from the batch and go unhandled.

Comment: @JesseSquire I am aware of that . But we are having huge surge of messages so cant really fill it since we almost hve exactly one message per batch . (I doubt tht is a good idea though )

Comment: There's no benefit to using the batch when you have a single message;  you may want to consider just calling the overload of `SendAsync` that accepts an enumerable.   You'll trigger an exception during publishing if your event is too large to succeed, but you'll save the overhead of creating/disposing the batch for a single message.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is publishing your batch to the Event Hubs gateway, where events will be routed to a partition.  For a successful publish operation, each event will be sent to one partition only.

"Successful" is the key in that phrase.  You're configuring your retry policy with a `TryTimeout` of 5 seconds and allowing 30 retries.  The duplication that you're seeing is most likely caused by your publish request timing out due to the very short interval, being successfully received by the service, but leaving the service unable to acknowledge success.  This will cause the client to consider the operation a failure and retry.

By default, the `TryTimeout` interval is 60 seconds.  I'm not sure why you've chosen to restrict the timeout to such a small value, but I'd strongly advise considering changes.  Respectfully, unless you've done profiling and measuring to prove that you need to make changes, I'd advise using the default values for retries in their entirety.

Comment: The reason I've chosen to push through such small window as we have huge barrage of messages coming in and any delay will cause customer escalations . Ours is more of like real time data ingestion hence larger retries is something we had to sacrifice

Comment: I don't know that your settings are helpful for your scenario, though I'm working with limited context.  If you're seeing timeouts, I'd start by reviewing your Event Hubs SKU,  number of TUs that you're using, the number of clients/connections in use, and the amount of concurrency that you've got during publishing.   You'll often see better throughput by doing intelligent batching than trying to single-publish under load.